# why var returnText = value as string not working?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Convert method that implements IValueConverter. My first statement is 
var returnText = value as string not working to take over the value as string. However, it doesn't work and when I was debugging, I found out the value of the "value" variable didn't assign over to returnText so the returnText is always null. It is odd. Does anybody know why?

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var returnText = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnText))
        {
           .....
```

Comment: are you sure that the type of value is string?

Comment: Are you sure `value` is of the type `string`? `value as string` will return `null` if `value` is not a `string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem and Solution**

The problem is that `as string` does not convert, it just casts the object to a string. If that doesn't work it will produce `null` instead. The object must be of string type originally, in this case that is obviously not the case.

One option that would likely work in your case is to call `.ToString()` on the object like so:

```
var returnText = value.ToString();
```

but please note that this really does depend on your object type, and what it's `.ToString()` method actually produces. You may get a value that you do not expect.

---

**Additional Recommendations**

As Tim has commented, `ToString()` will throw an exception if the object is `null` to begin with. It is recommended to test for this before calling any method on the object. Something like this will do:

```
string returnText = null;
if(value != null)
    returnText = value.ToString();
```

---

**Further Reading**

[See here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx). A couple of useful quotes from that link:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

and

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Comment: Note that if `value` is `null`, this will throw an exception. You could do `(value ?? "").ToString()` if you want to default it to an empty string.

Comment: @TimS.: Good point. Note that I didn't use your one-liner as I wanted to make the code as self-explanatory as possible. Your example would likely confuse the OP if they are not familiar with the syntax

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var returnText = value==null ? "": value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this *var returnText = value as string;* means: Try to **cast** value as `string` if not, return null.

as (C# Reference) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx

Why **System.Convert.ToString()** instead of `.ToString()`......

I'd rather use `var returnText = System.Convert.ToString(value);` because this will use the `IConvertable` interface. The ToString() could give a screwed-up result. (like classnames etc)

More info: *Convert.ToString Method* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx

Comment: It looks Convert won't work because it is a Convert method itself.

Comment: You should use the fullname (with namespace): System.Convert.ToString()